# Restricting contacts in groups using ACL roles

Tags: acl, roles

We want to create a role for a certain set of users in WP/Civi - to have access to only a certain group of contacts.

Here's what we have done.

- Added the Members plugin to create new roles
- Assigned that role to a WP user
- In the Group of contacts settings -enabled Access Control (under Group Type)
- Under Access Control > WordPress Access Control - disabled all the areas this user should not have access to when they log in
- Under Access Control > 1. Manage Roles > Created a Role under
- Under Access Control > 2. Assign Users to CiviCRM ACL Roles > Assigned the Role created in the previous step and assigned it to the group with the Access Control to that group (options is anabled)
- Under Access Control > 3. Manage ACLs >

  - Added an ACL
  - Added description
  - Added the Role
  - Gave Operation of View
  - Type of Data = A group of contacts
  - Group = the group with the Access Control enabled

If I log in as that person, all the features are missing that I disabled under WordPress Access Control, so that is working.
However, the person can still access all the of contacts they should not have access to.

We have followed all the instructions here https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/ and followed this video https://youtu.be/_fIw1ovN_-I but somewhere this a step missing that we are clearly overlooking.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you removed the 'View all Contacts', 'Edit all Contacts' permissions at this stage: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/initial-set-up/permissions-and-access-control/#access-control-permissions-in-wordpress

Comment: Thank you @Aidan, a little closer now. When I log into the person's profile now, they can only see their own account

Comment: It might be easier if you describe what you want to achieve.  From your phrase 'the group with the Access Control enabled' - I wonder whether your understanding is not quite correct.  That setting means the group can be used in an ACL to grant members of that group additional access beyond what they have from the CMS permissions.  There are 2 groups involved: Group A (step 2) is given a role that has access to the records of Group B (step 3).

Comment: Thanks @Aidan I have updated the description above with what we are trying to do. i.e. give someone a role and only allow them access to a certain group of contacts. Will check the rest of your comment in a moment

Comment: Hi @Aidan - wondered if you had managed to see the above description change? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Aidan - we've not yet managed to figure this one out, if you wouldn't mind shedding some light on it please?